# Drag and Drop icons to Home Screen

Tags: java, android, view, drag-and-drop, layout-inflater

**Update:** 
to understand my question, here is what i need to achieve:
Drag icon from App drawer to home screen (**if possible** not in a gridview) like in the pic,

[image]

**Old (this just to learn how this works):**

I'm trying to implement dragging clickable icons from a `ListView` to a `customView` with no container(`Listview or Gridview...`) inside the same Activity or another, here is a picture for you to understand more:

[image]

but when i put the icon in the right area **i don't see the object**, in the log i see: `I/ViewRootImpl﹕ Reporting drop result: true`

[image]

here my code:

```
class MyDragListener implements View.OnDragListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            ...
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                LinearLayoutAbsListView itemo = (LinearLayoutAbsListView)findViewById(R.id.paneko);
                View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
                itemo.addView(child);
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
             default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

My XML file:

```
...
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <com.moapps.elfassimounir.simple.LinearLayoutAbsListView
        android:id="@+id/paneuj"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </com.moapps.elfassimounir.simple.LinearLayoutAbsListView>

    <com.moapps.elfassimounir.simple.LinearLayoutAbsListView
        android:id="@+id/paneko"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    </com.moapps.elfassimounir.simple.LinearLayoutAbsListView>
</LinearLayout>

 ...
```

*Any infos or references (tutorials, docs...) would be very helpful*

Comment: What are you doing on this line LinearLayoutAbsListView newParent = (LinearLayoutAbsListView)v; , is v the view with id pane3? If so how are you setting the adapter for this view when there is no listview defined for this view?

Comment: no this code is with the Listview just to give you an idea of what i did

Comment: Again what is v in LinearLayoutAbsListView newParent = (LinearLayoutAbsListView)v; with respect to your xml

Comment: yes @random v is the view with id pane3

Comment: can you confirm if passedItem is added to destList and newParent.absListView referes to a listview inside pane3?

Comment: yes but i have exception

Comment: but i got null pointer exception because of this line " ItemBaseAdapter destAdapter = (ItemBaseAdapter)(newParent.absListView.getAdapter());"

Comment: @random i've updated my question, please take a look

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at adding a view to the WindowManager(WM). When you long press on an item to be dragged, create your own bitmap of that item and add it to the WM, so that it can be moved without view boundary constraints. When you receive a ACTION_UP or an equivalent event, map your current x,y to the actual view that is directly below the dragged item (Rect classs might be helpful). You can then add this item to that particular view.

Comment: hi Jignesh, first upvoted and thanks for explaining this, it seems like you've worked with android launcher, now i’m studying the code source of "launcher3", i understand your answer but i can’t find where (class ) they did create the bitmap and add it to the WM (i'm looking for an example to start with). by the way ACTION_UP... and Rect class are very helpful.