# My Launcher Based off androids launcher 3 ASOP doesn't open on samsung galaxy tab s

Tags: android, xml

hey guys I'm working on a launcher that is based off Launcher 3 form AOSP it works perfectly on my nexus 7 tablet and all my android phones I just got the samsung galaxy tab s 8.4 and when I try to run it it crashes before it launchers heres what logcat says:

```
04-10 07:46:57.757: E/ActivityThread(23606): Failed to find provider info for com.android.launcher2.settings
04-10 07:46:57.897: E/AndroidRuntime(23606): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-10 07:46:57.897: E/AndroidRuntime(23606): Process: com.android.launcher3, PID: 23606
04-10 07:46:57.897: E/AndroidRuntime(23606): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.launcher3/com.android.launcher3.Launcher}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #16: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
04-10 07:46:57.897: E/AndroidRuntime(23606):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2404)
04-10 07:46:57.897: E/AndroidRuntime(23606):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2464)
04-10 07:46:57.897: E/AndroidRuntime(23606):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
04-10 07:46:57.897: E/AndroidRuntime(23606):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
04-10 07:46:57.897: E/AndroidRuntime(23606):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-10 07:46:57.897: E/AndroidRuntime(23606):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
04-10 07:46:57.897: E/AndroidRuntime(23606):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
04-10 07:46:57.897: E/AndroidRuntime(23606):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-10 07:46:57.897: E/AndroidRuntime(23606):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-10 07:46:57.897: E/AndroidRuntime(23606):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
04-10 07:46:57.897: E/AndroidRuntime(23606):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
04-10 07:46:57.897: E/AndroidRuntime(23606):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-10 07:46:57.897: E/AndroidRuntime(23606): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #16: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
04-10 07:46:57.897: E/AndroidRuntime(23606):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:492)
04-10 07:46:57.897: E/AndroidRuntime(23606):    at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:6203)
04-10 07:46:57.897: E/AndroidRuntime(23606):    at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:6372)
04-10 07:46:57.897: E/AndroidRuntime(23606):    at android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(FrameLayout.java:615)
04-10 07:46:57.897: E/AndroidRuntime(23606):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.generateLayoutParams(FrameLayout.java:559)
04-10 07:46:57.897: E/AndroidRuntime(23606):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.generateLayoutParams(FrameLayout.java:56)
04-10 07:46:57.897: E/AndroidRuntime(23606):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:486)
04-10 07:46:57.897: E/AndroidRuntime(23606):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
04-10 07:46:57.897: E/AndroidRuntime(23606):    at com.android.launcher3.Launcher.getQsbBar(Launcher.java:3427)
04-10 07:46:57.897: E/AndroidRuntime(23606):    at com.android.launcher3.SearchDropTargetBar.setup(SearchDropTargetBar.java:72)
04-10 07:46:57.897: E/AndroidRuntime(23606):    at com.android.launcher3.Launcher.setupViews(Launcher.java:1325)
04-10 07:46:57.897: E/AndroidRuntime(23606):    at com.android.launcher3.Launcher.onCreate(Launcher.java:437)
04-10 07:46:57.897: E/AndroidRuntime(23606):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5539)
04-10 07:46:57.897: E/AndroidRuntime(23606):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
04-10 07:46:57.897: E/AndroidRuntime(23606):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2368)
04-10 07:46:57.897: E/AndroidRuntime(23606):    ... 11 more
```

I know it says the error is at line 16 in the xml but what xml file theres 30 xml files so if you have any ideas please let me know

The device is a Samsung Galaxy Tab S running 4.4.2

any help would be awesome

Thanks in advance

Comment: `"Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #16: You must supply a layout_width attribute."`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! the xml in question is located in: res/layout-sw720p/search_bar.xml

on line 16 you need to add the following code:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

This fixed the crashing issue I hope this helps anyone else who is having this issue!

Comment: can you please explain me how in the launcher3 they create the affect to Drag icon from App drawer to home screen (workspace),here i'm asking a pretty similar question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29410875/drag-and-drop-icons-to-home-screen