# Android : How to make a scrollable layout with dragable icons for accounts in an activity

Tags: android, android-layout

I have to develop an android application where i need to implement a layout as below in my activity.
 [image: Layout with movable icons]

Below is the structure for each icon on it.
[image: Structure for each icon]

I need to implement the above structure inside a scrollable layout.I need a EditText to enter amount and a 3 dot button at the top right corner of each icon as specified in the image.I have a list which contains a number of accounts from the database and i need to implement an icon with this layout for each of that account in the list.This should display according to the number of accounts in the database,it will varies in each time.The horizontal view may contain 3 or 4 icons as the screen size and the vertical view contains rows as the size of the list.I think this is similar to the application icons in our android phone screen with some extra features.My main question that how to implement the above structure in a scrollable layout? I don't know how to do these things.Please guide me to do these.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_drag_and_drop.htm

Comment: How can i implement a design as above inside a scrollable layout

Comment: Show us what you've tried

Comment: Check this link for dragable button or icon. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14807014/draggable-image-button http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29410875/drag-and-drop-icons-to-home-screen

Comment: I don't think dragging is an issue here.But how to design icons and its data as above??

Comment: You should use card view to design this kind of layout.

Comment: @jaydroider does i can add textview,Edittext,image and button inside a cardview??Also is it possible to allocate cards horizontally as per the screen size??

Comment: @KJEjava48 What is issue in view? Make dynamic layout Relative and add view into that layout dynamically when need.Try this approach it will work.

Comment: @SandeepTiwari I don't know which one to use.If views works fine please point out some useful links that will be useful for me

Comment: @jaydroider   is it possible to use this CardView in Android Jellybean???

Comment: @KJEjava48 i am not sure about it but for kitkat and above version it is possible to use.

Comment: @jaydroider so is there any alternative way to do this??

Answer (score 2):

you have to make 2  layouts 1 main layout which will hold your recycler view and second will be recycler view 1 row .
you have to design row like you have shown . take a cardview as root element in the row ..then take linearlayout to hold your 4 images and data ... after that make recycler adapter to initialize recycler view from your data ..or or ...

just use recycler view with  grid layout ..which will have 4 columns and infinite rows .. but you should have sound knowledge of recycler view for that study links below 
http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Comment: Is this possible to move/drag these cards to the trash??

Comment: for drag and drop you should study drag and drop  features which i haven't tried yet sorry but most of the things are possible you have to dig deep .. i will suggest one library you should study that and implement grid's side sliding trash option for now https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout   see its demo i m talking about the grid which have trash appearance to the left side

Comment: is it possible to use this GridLayout,RecyclerView and CardView in Android Jellybean???

Comment: yes you have to use support library ... in your dependency section

Comment: like these compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.+'  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.+'  see this link for all support features [link]http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library

Comment: if you are satisfied with my answer please accept it as answer and up vote answer and comments thanks :)

Comment: its not working with the supported library.I have downloaded the jar for GridLayout,CardView and ReclyclerView and put it in the library folder but when i extend the RecyclerView.Adapter some errors occur.Also showing configure build path error.

Comment: ok you have to make custom adapter for it and override RecyclerView adapter and then thr in onbind view initialize your views letme show you an example

Comment: i shared this gist with you read it and try to understand what i am saying ..then you just have to set this adapter to your recycler recyclerview.setadapter(new RecyclerViewCustomAdapter(this,dataset)); like this https://gist.github.com/arifnoumankhan/75e8392d0868a08484b6

Comment: oh man you dont have to download jars manually .. if you are using android studio with gradle ...  if you dont have android studio i will highly recommend you android studio 1.5.1 stable ... if u have  just open your app build.gradle file and  and there you have to put your compile time dependency in the dependency section ... then sync your project :)

Comment: i am not using gradle in my project..

Comment: you are using android studio ?